# Finding limit at $1/2$ not using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus

Find
$$
\lim_{x \to 1/2}\left[%
\frac{\arcsin\left(x\right) - \arcsin\left(1/2\right)}{x - 1/2}\right]
$$

I've gotten the answer to be $2/\sqrt{3}$ due to L'Hôpital's rule but I'm trying to find it using an elementary way (non-L'Hôpital method) and don't seem to have much luck :(

Help ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Consider using Latex or at least putting Brackets

Comment: This is finding the derivative of $\arcsin$ at $1/2$.

Comment: @Lucian That was not an answer: using the derivative is just using a special case of l'Hôpital's theorem, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

So that there won't be complains:

$$\lim_{x\to 1/2}\frac{\arcsin x-\arcsin\frac12}{x-\frac12}=:\left(\arcsin\frac12\right)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac12}}$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way:

The statement is that $\arcsin'(\frac12)=2/\sqrt3$. Finding the derivative of $\arcsin$ can be done as follows:

From the definition of $\arcsin$ we have:
$$\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$$
Deriving both sides gives:
$$\cos(x) \arcsin'(\sin(x))=1\\
\arcsin'(\sin(x))=\frac1{\cos(x)}$$
Using trigonometric identifies gives:
$$\arcsin'(\sin(x))=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}$$
Which means:
$$\arcsin'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Then
$$\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\arcsin x-\arcsin\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\arcsin'(\frac12)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-(\frac12)^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{\frac34}}=\frac2{\sqrt3}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is computing the derivative of $\arcsin$ at $1/2$. It's easier if you invert your fraction and set $\arcsin x=y$.

If $x\to\frac{1}{2}$, then $y\to\frac{\pi}{6}$, so
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{\arcsin x-\arcsin\frac{1}{2}}=
\lim_{y\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin y-\frac{1}{2}}{y-\frac{\pi}{6}}
$$
Now set $y-\frac{\pi}{6}=z$ and your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin(z+\frac{\pi}{6})-\frac{1}{2}}{z}
$$
that easily reduces to a couple of fundamental limits by expanding the sine at the numerator.

---

As usual, I find such kind of exercises a bad way to teach limits.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $y=\arcsin x$ and use the [sum to product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) rule to reduce the limit to 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t} = 1.
$$

Comment: Until I googled it some 2 minutes ago I never knew that Prosta...whatever (simple trigonometric identities), but the limit is not $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: I added the correct reference. I realized that "prostaferesi" was the italian name... The result is not 1 but you reduce your computation to that one.

Comment: It still is confusing and misleading, imo: what you get is the limit $$\lim_{y\to \pi/6}\frac{y-\pi/6}{\sin y-1/2}$$ and this limit is *not* one...

Comment: Transform $\sin y - \sin\pi/6$ into a product...

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{I \equiv \lim_{x \to 1/2}\left[%
{\arcsin\left(x\right) - \arcsin\left(1/2\right) \over x - 1/2}\right]\,,\qquad
 \mu \equiv \arcsin\pars{1/2}.}$

> \begin{align}
> I&= \lim_{x \to \mu}\bracks{x - \mu \over \sin\pars{x} - 1/2}
> =
> \lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{x \over \sin\pars{x + \mu} - 1/2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \lim_{x \to 0}
> \bracks{x \over \sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{\mu} + \cos\pars{x}\sin\pars{\mu} - 1/2}
> =
> \lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{x \over \sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{\mu}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over \root{1 - \sin^{2}\pars{\mu}}}\,
> \lim_{x \to 0}{1 \over \sin\pars{x}/x} = {1 \over \root{1 - \pars{1/2}^{2}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{x \to 1/2}\left[%
{\arcsin\left(x\right) - \arcsin\left(1/2\right) \over x - 1/2}\right]=
{2\root{3} \over 3}}
$$